# I want to randomize letters in words, from my <textarea> input

Tags: javascript, html, random, output, textarea

I would like to know how to change up words a bit from my textarea input. I wouldn't want all the words in the sentence to be scrambled, rather only (some) of the letters in (some) of the words. The word order has to be the same.

I was thinking of using var string_array = string.split(""); but I couldn't find a lot of documentation on this and I couldn't find any other options that would be good for me, either.

Does anybody have suggestions in how to do this?

```html
<!--Made by MysteriousDuck#5764-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="textchanger.js"></script>
    <title>Text changer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h1> Text Changer </h1>
        <h2> CAPS text changer</h2>

        <textarea type="text" autofocus="true" placeholder="input text" id="inputText" value="Input Value"
            spellcheck="false"></textarea>
        <button class="button button1" onclick="myConvertFunction()">Convert</button>
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="CoNvErTeD tExT" id="converted" value="Clear" readonly="true"
            spellcheck="false"></textarea>
        <button class="button button1" onclick="myCopyFunction(); eraseText();">Copy</button>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
/* Made by MysteriousDuck#5764 */

function myConvertFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    var foo = x.split("");
    var string = "";
    for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            string += foo[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
            string += foo[i];
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("converted").value = string;
}

function myCopyFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("converted");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    eraseText();
}

function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("converted").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inputText").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inputText").focus();
}

function randomizeLetters() {
    var x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Some advice: Questions that start with "I want..." are often not well received and aren't a good fit for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
function scramble(text) {
    let words = text.split(' ');

    words = words.map(word => {
        if (word.length > 2) {
            return word.split('').sort(() => 0.5-Math.random()).join('');
        }

        return word;
    });

    console.log(words);

    return words.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it does not work, do you see what I did wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/MysteriousDuck/tph96ncL/33/

Comment: `scramble` function just return scrambled word and you didn't use it inside your function to manipulate your input value.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But how would I make it be able to work along with my capitalize feature?

Comment: You can use your last random capitalize function first then pass string to scramble function.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/oLjcezwt/)

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I can change the probability of it changing and I can also change on what word length it'll have a chance to change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to capitalize alternate characters. If that is the case then you can split the value of the `textarea` and then use `map` on the array. `map` will return a new array. Inside map callback check the `index` of the character. If it is even then convert to upper case. Since `map` returns a new array, you can use `join` to create a new string from array

```js
function myConvertFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  var foo = x.split("");
  var string = foo.map(function(item, index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  })

  document.getElementById("converted").value = string.join('');
}

function myCopyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("converted");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  eraseText();
}

function eraseText() {
  document.getElementById("converted").value = "";
  document.getElementById("inputText").value = "";
  document.getElementById("inputText").focus();
}

function randomizeLetters() {
  var x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1> Text Changer </h1>
  <h2> CAPS text changer</h2>

  <textarea type="text" autofocus="true" placeholder="input text" id="inputText" value="Input Value" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <button class="button button1" onclick="myConvertFunction()">Convert</button>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="CoNvErTeD tExT" id="converted" value="Clear" readonly="true" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  <button class="button button1" onclick="myCopyFunction(); eraseText();">Copy</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know, along with me wanting to capitalize every odd letter, I would also like it to scramble some of the letters in some of my words.

Comment: What exactly mean by scramble?

Comment: Example. The input is: this is a text message the output is: ThIs iS A TeXt mEsSaGe. Now I would like it to, along with capitilazing every odd letter, randomly mix up some of the letters in the words. So input is: this is a text message  output is: ThSi iS A tXeT MsEaSaGe

Answer (score 0):

The below function takes a string as argument. Scrambles any word in that string randomly. Also capitalizes any letter in the word randomly

```
function randomizeString(sentence) {

    const words = sentence.split(' ');
    return words.map(word => {
        const flag = getRandomInt(2);
        return flag ? scrambleWord(word) : word;
    }).join(' ');

    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }

    function scrambleWord (word) {
        var scramble = '';
        word = word.split('');
        while (word.length > 0) {
            scramble +=  word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
        }
        return randomCapitalizeWord(scramble);
    }

    function randomCapitalizeWord(word) {
        return word.split('').map(letter => {
            const flag = getRandomInt(2);
            return flag ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter;
        }).join('');
    }
}
```